# Please tell me if I'm right

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm reading about vector spaces and I'm too confused with the terms. Please let me know if the following inferences are correct.

1. If I perform a linear operation on the components of a vector, then the result belongs to a dual space.
2. If I perform a linear operation on vectors, then the result belongs to a vector space.

Comment: Welcome to Mahs SX! I would say ‘yes’ but your formulation is quite vague. Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: Getting a component of a vector is a dual space operation, so the answer to 1st question is yes.

Answer (score 1):

for $2$:

*yes*. If not, we have a linearity property, which says roughly that for a linear transformation $f:V \to W$, $T(v+u)=T(v)+T(u)$. But note that $T(v), T(u) \in W$, so $W$ should be a space where addition makes sense, and $T(kv)=k T(v)$, for some scalar $k$, so scalar multiplication should also make sense. This essentially means that to define a map as linear, kind of requires that after applying a linear operation, the result belongs to a vector space.

for $1$: It is unclear what you mean to me, but I would say that the dual space consists of  linear operations you can do on a vector, so that the result is a scalar. In particular, it consists of linear operations $\phi:V \to k$, where $k$ is the base field.